# Apart from "g", how to replace all characters from a string with a " "?

Tags: ruby

How do  I remove all characters, numbers and symbols except for `"g"` from a string and replace it with a `" "`?

```
string = "bi2gger 1is 00ggooder"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gsub` is overkill here. Use [`String#tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-tr):

```
string = "bi2gger 1is 00ggooder"
string.tr("^g", " ")
# => "   gg         gg     "
```

This will return a new string. To instead modify the original string, use [`tr!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-tr-21).

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/KJPY

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) with`[^g]` which replaces all characters except for `g`, with a `" "`:

```
string.gsub(/[^g]/," ") #=> "   gg         gg     "
```

Answer (score 1):

**This can be achieved with Regular Expressions**

This problem can be boiled down to regular expressions, as the comments stated.
In order to replace every 'g' character from your string you can use a regular expression: `/[^g]/`

So the simplest solution is to use `String#gsub` and the regular expression to change all the characters that match that rule. ( Note that you also have the bang version of this method `String#gsub!` that will replace your original string )

You can read/try regular expressions at a site: [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) can be used here.

```
string = "bi2gger 1is 00ggooder"

string.gsub(/./) { |s| s=='g' ? 'g' : ' ' }
  #=>    "   gg         gg     "
```

Comment: Readers: I formerly had `h = Hash.new { ' ' }.tap { |h| h["g"] = "g" }; 
string.gsub(/./,h)`. @Jordan's suggestion is an improvement but it's still a pretty lame answer. (What was I thinking?) I therefore changed it, but still prefer Jordon's answer.